# How to speed up 2D 'full' convolution (multiple kernels) with matrix multiplication?

Tags: c++, matrix, neural-network, convolution

I'm working with convolutional deep neural networks (CRBM in particular). I need to perform several 'valid' convolution and several 'full' convolutions. I need to optimize their speed. I'm working with C++.

In the case of the 'valid' convolution I have been able to speed it up by around 50% by rearranging the image (This is the equivalent of *im2col* in Matlab) and multiplying (matrix multiply) by the matrix of kernels (one per line), replacing several convolutions by one matrix multiplication.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to gain anything with 'full' convolution. I know that I can also rearrange the image (using an equivalent of *convmtx2* in Matlab), but simply doing the rearranging of the image matrix to a convolution matrix is already much slower (almost an order of magnitude) than doing all the convolutions. The convolution matrix becomes large very quickly.

Is there a good practical way of speeding 'full' convolution (with multiple kernels) up with matrix multiplication in C++ ? Perhaps, an efficient way of computing convmtx2 ?

Comment: I'm confused... you're saying that you are doing this in C++ but you are giving matlab commands. Are you trying to port matlab code to C++?

Comment: @RyanP Sorry for the confusion, I'm simply giving the equivalents in Matlab but I have coded an equivalent of im2col and convmtx2 in C++.

Comment: Here is described how the caffe framework performs convolution: https://github.com/Yangqing/caffe/wiki/Convolution-in-Caffe:-a-memo , maybe it can give you some help

Comment: @Mailerdaimon This is what I do for the 'valid' convolution. Unfortunately, this is not directly adaptable to 'full' convolution.